# Dispatch different function depending on type of generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to write a function that lets me dispatch on the type of the generic passed in. I don't care about the runtime value, JUST the compile time type:

```
const value: any;
const x: DateTime = parseAs<DateTime>(value)
const y: string = parseAs<string>(value)
const z: number = parseAs<number>(value)
```

The implementation of each `parseAs` function we can assume is irrelevant (just that it takes a value of `any`, and returns the type in `A`

Is this possible? I.e. calling a diff function depending on the generic param passed in. I don't care about the value param passed in, I just want to blindly call a parse function on it

Comment: You cannot, due to type erasure.

Comment: But all of this is at compile time is it not. I.e, can the typescript compiler not replace my calls with inlined functions that are specific to the type I need?

Comment: Well, if there are going to be different functions implementing the different behaviours, why not just give the functions different names and call the function with the appropriate name? For example, what's wrong with `parseAsDateTime` instead of `parseAs<DateTime>`? The different functions are going to need different names in the compiled Javascript anyway, and Typescript doesn't have a feature which would cause a function call like `parseAs<...>(...)` to be compiled to a function call with a different function name.

Comment: Yeah, different names is certainly possible. I was hoping from an ergonomics point of view, there might be a solution.

Comment: Well, really Typescript is just there to help you avoid certain kinds of mistakes and bugs when you write Javascript code. As the Typescript handbook says: *"Remember: Type annotations never change the runtime behavior of your program."* So no feature of Typescript will ever cause your code to do something different depending on whether it has a type annotation or not; `const x: DateTime = parseAs<DateTime>(value)` must *always* do the same thing as `const x = parseAs(value)`, the only difference between those two can be whether the Typescript compiler reports an error or a warning or not.

Comment: Yeah, this is [TypeScript Design Non-Goal #5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals): TypeScript generally will not "emit different code based on the results of the type system", so it's basically not going to happen (:closes eyes and refuses to look at `const enum`:).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because type information is erased before the emit step during compilation, it's not possible to affect runtime values using type information.

However, if ergonomics is your goal, then you can use an overloaded function to achieve a strongly-typed result like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEElQBwJwUwM4FcC2dQBcAWBLBo9QBDTATynVIHslQBjeIjOAEwBpQEqAoECAcgA2gznAwFxGKqAAiTdADMqMTLnxwAHkRRRBcAFzcM5dHOYAVHGlABeWfIDc3IydAAFIjARwAYspRMtqD8ZnCWaPygAD7BCBgwOAB2AOaRMfyJqABGcDD8TtwKSIl0GDhUidCe3gCCCAAUSjABGPrBoeFw-BwAbkSCSAagxQDWiVQA7okAlG0dVnBORSVlFVVecHWN-kxt-HEJKd2gfQNDo+NTs5zxSclLxaXllVDVmw1NLXuZKDl5vf1Bm0LpMZm0fn8Hitnutah8dq13G8-M0mACzsDEmNQdNQABvbigUB8GqlJD9QSkAg6PRoRIYQmgeAYJAwSrFFhwBRJVjEfBERKkJwAX2cfHMWDg7IQdwI+AAVkg4nzQLlkhUqCgcHQVcgoLpSLKSMYKKBklLctrDJy6IJPOg6BVlacgcRBU5XhstiF5J1ji64NMHMSwPM0NxPXD6vtbkd0YMgyGbodkhG3t6Ibl-YDA8G+JmYNwgA)

```ts
// I presume this is a type you created, so
// I'll set it to Date for this example:
type DateTime = Date;

type ParseFormat = 'DateTime' | 'string' | 'number';

function parseAs(format: 'DateTime', value: unknown): DateTime;
function parseAs(format: 'string', value: unknown): string;
function parseAs(format: 'number', value: unknown): number;
function parseAs(format: ParseFormat, value: unknown) {
  // Actually implement
  return undefined as any;
}

// Then using is just as ergonomic as supplying a type generic:
declare const value: any;
parseAs('DateTime', value); // DateTime
parseAs('string', value); // string
parseAs('number', value); // number
```